# update mongodb collection on meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

i have a Meteor app to list name and number,
i can insert and delete names and numbers and now i'm trying to add a button to change the name or the number field 
how can i do this in meteor

this is my code

.html

```
 <head>
    <title>Meteor_CRUD</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> index}}
</body>

<template name="index">
    <h1>List</h1>
    <table> 
        <thead>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Number</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="name" type="text"/></td>
                <td><input class="number" type="text"/></td>
                <td><button class="add">add</button></td>
        </tr>
        {{#each list}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{number}}</td>
                <td><button class="del">del</button></td>
                <td><button class="change">change</button></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

.js

```
List = new Meteor.Collection("list");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.index.helpers({
    list : function () {
        return List.find();  
    }
});

Template.index.events({
    'click .del' : function (evt, tmpl) {
        List.remove(this._id);
    },

    'click .add' : function (evt, tmpl) {
        var name = tmpl.find(".name").value;
        var number = tmpl.find(".number").value;

        List.insert({name: name, number: number});

        tmpl.find(".name").value = '';
        tmpl.find(".number").value = '';
    },

    'click .change' : function (evt, tmpl) {
        //List.update(this._id);
    }
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.startup(function () {
      // code to run on server at startup
   });
}
```

can someone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the field, first,find the document using some field(here _id),then push the changes to the document like below

```
'click .change' : function (evt, tmpl) {
        //List.update(this._id);
         var name=this.name;
         var number=this.number;
         List.update({_id:this._id},{$push:{name:name,number:number}});
    }
```

Make sure that you have permission to update the collection by inserting the following code in server side

```
List.allow({
            update:function(userId, doc, fields, modifier)
              {
            //anyone can update the collection
            //you can write some filters to restrict the updating to only owner of the document

               return true;
              }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks iAmME, but it didn't work, it gave me this error

Comment: Exception while simulating the effect of invoking '/list/update' 
Error {stack: "Error: Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array↵  …?ee011232935d2eb0932c11c435cc634c23fe08c7:352:26)", message: "Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array"}
message: "Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array"